# SonarQube 6.4 and LDAP plugin 2.2: Connection refused though ldapsearch works

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube

I'm baffled by this. Working my way through all the answers I've found here on Stackoverflow I tried all I now. Hence posting and asking here.

```
### sonar.properties
# AD AUTHENTICATION
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://server.domain.com:389
ldap.bindDn=cn=service_account,ou=mygroup,dc=domain,dc=com
ldap.bindPassword=*********
ldap.authentication=simple
ldap.realm=domain.com
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=mygroup,dc=domain,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user )(sAMAccountName ={login}))

## ERROR in log
2017.07.27 05:10:27 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection: FAIL
2017.07.27 05:10:27 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapException: Unable to open LDAP connection
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Using ldapsearch with the same connection string (URL, bind DN, password, search base, ...) works like a charm.
Can anybody point me in the direction or provide some insight?

Thanks in advance,

Eric V.

Comment: As is there's not much to comment. You should enable debug logs and edit your post with the full set of startup logs, including complete stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas B.
I put the debug web.log in GitHub Gist:
https://gist.github.com/EricVS/9c738b0f63f71eecbf8fc6191c5b98bc